# How to shrink a responsive image within a flex container with fixed height

Tags: css, image, flexbox, responsive

I want to display some divs containing an image and two divs with text in it in a flexbox container with a fixed height.
These divs represent tracks with an album cover, the song name and the artists name.

Like this:

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="track">
    <img class="track--image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/">
    <div class="track--artist-name">Artist</div>
    <div class="track--track-name">Song</div>
  </div>
  <div class="track">
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.track {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 9rem;
  color: black;
}

.track--image {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.track--name,
.track--artist-name {
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is that the image has a width of 100% to fit into its parent div. But this also implies that it overflows its parent. And also the two divs within the `track` div get pushed outside its parents.

How do I prevent the image from beeing too big for its parent div so that either the image and the two divs fit inside the parent?

I also prepared a codepen to better describe the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBQGRb

**EDIT:**

My expectation looks something like this:
[image]
As you can see the light grey container is my flex-container within I want to have my track divs. The image and those two texts should fit within even if the height of the flex-container changes.

Comment: What about using `height: 100%` instead of `width: 100%` in `.track .track--image`?

Comment: then the image fits into its parent but the two divs `.track--artist-name` and `.track--name` overflow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem now like this:

```css
.track--image {
  height: 66%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

This works not for every height of the flex-container but is okay in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Does switching height to auto in your .flex-container give you the desired outcome,

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**After comment**

All I've done below is add a small amount of padding to the track container to get the image off the top border and forced the image to fit within the fluid-container by control the width.

```
.track .track--image {
  width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.track {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 9rem;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the constraint is that the flex-container has a fixed height. In my example a fixed pixel value for simplicity. It will be embedded in a grid layout which causes a fixed height...

Comment: Are you in that case able to increase the fixed height?

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your image class like this it works.

```
.track {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 9rem;
  color: black;

  .track--image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height:100%;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOadGO